# How to update record in local storage using ember data and localstorage adapter?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am new to emberjs and making one simple CRUD application. I am using ember data and [localstorage-adapter](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter) to save record in local storage of browser.

I am trying to update record using localstorage-adapter but it is throwing error.

I have listed my code here :

```
updatecontact: function(){//save data in local storage
        var fname = this.obj_form_edit_data.get('cont_data.fname');
        var lname = this.get('cont_data.lname');
        var email = this.get('cont_data.email');
        var contactno = this.get('cont_data.contactno');
        var gendertype = ((this.get('isMale') == true) ? true : false);
        var contactype = $(".selectpicker").val();
        Grid.ModalModel.updateRecords({ 
          fname: fname,
          lname: lname,
          email: email,
          contactno: contactno,
          gendertype: gendertype,
          contactype: contactype
        });
        this.get('store').commit();             
    }
```

I am getting following error using above code :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
if (!wasApplied) {
  Class.proto(); // prepare prototype...
}
o_defineProperty(this, GUID_KEY, undefinedDescriptor);
o_defineProperty(this, '_super', undefinedDescriptor);
var m = meta(this);
m.proto = this;
if (initMixins) {
  // capture locally so we can clear the closed over variable
  var mixins = initMixins;
  initMixins = null;
  this.reopen.apply(this, mixins);
}
if (initProperties) {
  // capture locally so we can clear the closed over variable
  var props = initProperties;
  initProperties = null;

  var concatenatedProperties = this.concatenatedProperties;

  for (var i = 0, l = props.length; i < l; i++) {
    var properties = props[i];

    Ember.assert("Ember.Object.create no longer supports mixing in other definitions, use createWithMixins instead.", !(properties instanceof Ember.Mixin));

    for (var keyName in properties) {
      if (!properties.hasOwnProperty(keyName)) { continue; }

      var value = properties[keyName],
          IS_BINDING = Ember.IS_BINDING;

      if (IS_BINDING.test(keyName)) {
        var bindings = m.bindings;
        if (!bindings) {
          bindings = m.bindings = {};
        } else if (!m.hasOwnProperty('bindings')) {
          bindings = m.bindings = o_create(m.bindings);
        }
        bindings[keyName] = value;
      }

      var desc = m.descs[keyName];

      Ember.assert("Ember.Object.create no longer supports defining computed properties.", !(value instanceof Ember.ComputedProperty));
      Ember.assert("Ember.Object.create no longer supports defining methods that call _super.", !(typeof value === 'function' && value.toString().indexOf('._super') !== -1));

      if (concatenatedProperties && indexOf(concatenatedProperties, keyName) >= 0) {
        var baseValue = this[keyName];

        if (baseValue) {
          if ('function' === typeof baseValue.concat) {
            value = baseValue.concat(value);
          } else {
            value = Ember.makeArray(baseValue).concat(value);
          }
        } else {
          value = Ember.makeArray(value);
        }
      }

      if (desc) {
        desc.set(this, keyName, value);
      } else {
        if (typeof this.setUnknownProperty === 'function' && !(keyName in this)) {
          this.setUnknownProperty(keyName, value);
        } else if (MANDATORY_SETTER) {
          Ember.defineProperty(this, keyName, null, value); // setup mandatory setter
        } else {
          this[keyName] = value;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
finishPartial(this, m);
delete m.proto;
finishChains(this);
this.init.apply(this, arguments);
```

} has no method 'updateRecords'

I am using following code to create new record which working fine :

```
savecontact: function(){//save data in local storage
        var fname = this.obj_form_edit_data.get('cont_data.fname');
        var lname = this.obj_form_edit_data.get('cont_data.lname');
        var email = this.obj_form_edit_data.get('cont_data.email');
        var contactno = this.obj_form_edit_data.get('cont_data.contactno');
        var gendertype = ((this.get('isMale') == true) ? true : false);
        var contactype = $(".selectpicker").text();
        Grid.ModalModel.createRecord({  
          fname: fname,
          lname: lname,
          email: email,
          contactno: contactno,
          gendertype: gendertype,
          contactype: contactype
        });
        this.get('store').commit(); 
    }
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @intuitivepixel: I have updated my question with error.

Comment: you may first fetch the record you want to update, change its properties and call `save`. 

Even if `updateRecords` would exist in LSAdapter it would require you do identify the records that should be edited and would probably take an array of objects not a single object as in your notation.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `updateRecords` as a plural, it should be `updateRecord`